# Windows doesn't fall into hibernation (err: 1017)

Tags: windows-8.1, hibernate

When I try to hibernate my Windows 8.1 Acer laptop it just turn off the screen and do no more, all the leds continue lighting. If I  touch the mouse or the key after that the screen turns on in no time.

I tried do that from command prompt:
`shutdown /h`

Same thing happend, cmd said this:

`The system has attempted to load or restore a file into the registry, but the specified file is not in a registry file format.(1017)`

This is fresh Windows install, hibernate stop working after first couple of updates.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that the Windows file which is responsible for hibernation is corrupted

There is a tool called System File Checker which would can scan the computer and then repair the windows corrupted or incomplete file.

Open the commnd prompt with run as administrator and then execute the command

```
sfc /scannow
```

It will regularly list the percentage of the file it has scanned. Once it is done,it would prompt the message that corrupted files are found and replaced.

We request you to try to execute the hibernate command.

```
shutdown /h
```